# Command 'qmake' failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt

I'm trying to install capybara-webkit for Ruby on Rails.  Initially, I had issues because the computer did not have `qmake` installed.  After getting that installed (Qt version 5.9.1 on Windows 10) I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\ajsmart\Documents\RORapp>gem install capybara-webkit
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20171027-15232-1js9zey.rb extconf.rb
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-gl-dir
        --without-gl-dir
        --with-gl-include
        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
        --with-gl-lib
        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' failed

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/gem_make.out

C:\Users\ajsmart\Documents\RORapp>
```

To my admittedly untrained eye, the configuration options I have are okay.  It seems to be a `qmake` error.  The thing is that `exit code 1` isn't very helpful when trying to diagnose what's going on here.

The following are my current software versions, if it's relevant:

Windows 10

Qt version 5.9.1

Qmake version 3.1

Ruby gems 2.6.13

Ruby version 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]

**EDIT:**

I followed [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/81290/cannot-run-compiler-cl) feed trying to figure out my issue as it relates to the following  error code: `Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?` Unfortunately, that wasn't enough since my particular error has nothing to do with MySQL like the comment feed suggested.

Comment: I followed the comments in the link included, and have been unable to solve my issue. https://forum.qt.io/topic/81290/cannot-run-compiler-cl

Answer (score 0):

I think the relevant error is `Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?`. Looks like `cl.exe` is the C/C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio - do you have that installed?